failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task - PyCharm Interpreter Creation
I'm currently trying to debug my containerized Django application using this tutorial. But unfortunately, I receive the attached error, when I try to create a new Python interpreter. This video shows my steps: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ZGIKggCIws
"Python interpreter process exited with a non-zero exit code 1  Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/home/leo/Desktop/development/daytistics/app/backend/.venv/bin/python": stat /home/leo/Desktop/development/daytistics/app/backend/.venv/bin/python: no such file or directory: unknown"
Here are the relevant parts of my docker-compose file:
name: daytistics
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:16
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: mydb
      POSTGRES_USER: myuser
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mypassword
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  django:
    image: python:3.12-slim
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/app
    working_dir: /app
    command: >
      /bin/sh -c "pip install poetry &&
      poetry config virtualenvs.in-project true &&
      poetry install --no-root &&
      poetry run python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgres://myuser:mypassword@postgres:5432/mydb
      DJANGO_SECRET_KEY: "xuh%bc^1%m575%mv@@t87=f6_(i)%c=3jt-+obn&e%=+8qbm!f"
      DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS: "*"
      CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS: "http://localhost:3000"
      CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS: "http://localhost:3000"
      CSRF_ALLOWED_ORIGINS: "http://localhost:3000"
      FRONTEND_URL: http://nuxt:3000
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - postgres

volumes:
  postgres_data:


The corresponding Python executable exists. I also have access permissions.

Host paths like /home/leo/... won't necessarily exist in a container, and virtual environments don't necessarily work with different Pythons.  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  What's in your Dockerfile, and how are you starting the container?

I've added a youtube video and my docker-copose file

Does deleting the poetry config line from command: work?  Completely reinstalling your project every time you recreate the container isn't necessarily a best practice; for a development environment, can you use the Python on your host system, using Docker for the database but running the code outside a container?

When you run poetry run python it tries to run the python command within the venv. But the problem is python interpreter which is going to be run is symlink of the python3 in that virtual environment, and you cannot copy symlinks of something in your computer to the docker container.

Can you explain to me what I need to change then, please?

The simplest way is to remove the already existed .venv and build the new virtual env again:
rm -rf .venv &&
python3 -m venv .venv &&
...

put this right after pip install poetry
